# Relationship between tables in ms sql server

Tags: sql-server

A patient can select many tests, and a test can be selected by many patient.
Then what would be the structure of these tables and how the relationship can be established between them?

Comment: You're saying "totally new to C#" but I don't see how this question is in any way related to C#.

Comment: A question on SO is not how you begin to learn a skill. There are resources for learning if you google.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. This is far too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your table structure should be below

**PatientTable**
PatientId   int Primary Key,
PatientName varchar(50),
EmailId varchar(50)
Password  varchar(50)

**TestTable**
TestId  int Primary key,
TestName varchar(50)

**PatientTestTable**
PatientId int FK(PatientTable)
TestId int FK (TestTable)

This way you can give relationship to two tables. you need to understand funamental of RDBMS.

Comment: Thank you it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need 3 tables, Patient table, Test Table and PatientTest Table
with PatientID as foreign key fro Patient table and TestId as foreign key from Test table and you can add any other column ( like TestDatetime, TestResult ...)

Comment: _You will probably_ is a good way to recognise that this question isn't answerable and that it is _too broad_.